# Selenium: How do I click a link without it having a href identifier

Tags: python, selenium, google-shopping

I'm trying to use Selenium to get prices from Google Shopping. I've currently made it open Chrome, go to google shopping and search the product code, however I can't find a way to get it to click the product as I can't find an identifier for the href for it or find a way to get the product name so that I can make it click via a partial text match.

I've tried looking at other people having similar issues but they all seem to find a unique identifier for the link they're trying to click.

```py
class MyDialog:
    def __init__(self, parent):

        top = self.top = Toplevel(parent)

        Label(top, text="Product EAN:").pack()

        self.e = Entry(top, cursor = "xterm", width=25)
        self.e.pack(padx=40)

        b = Button(top, text="Submit", command=self.ok, cursor = "hand2")
        b.pack(pady=5)

    def ok(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get("http://www.google.co.uk/shopping")
        search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
        search_box.send_keys(self.e.get())
        search_box.submit()

root = Tk()
d = MyDialog(root)
root.wait_window(d.top)
```

There might be a way to take the product name and then partial match that text to click instead but I'm unsure how I'd go about that too. My end goal is to scrape the sellers and their price from Google Shopping and then format it and output it into a file - I've tried other methods of doing this but Selenium seems by far the least complicated.

Comment: what is `self.e.get()` ?

Comment: That's just an input from the user which comes from a textbox input

Comment: yes, Could you share that, would be helpful to write the answer.

Comment: Probably it action will be done in event. Analyze the element who has the event and click it

Comment: I've added the whole code now

Comment: After search_box = driver.find element... (Dont do send keys and submit, just search_box.click()), then probably you can send_keys to search whatever you want

Comment: The end goal is to be able to input a EAN (and maybe once I've got it working for one, then I'll change to input multiple), it searches Google Shopping for it, takes the sellers and their prices and saves them into a file before closing Chrome.